# Importing animations in Unreal flickers

Tags: animation, import, .fbx, unreal-engine, actions

I have created a few actions in Blender and I'm trying to export them to Unreal. The problem is the zero frame in Unreal is the T-pose, which causes the animation to flicker when looping. I could always remove the frame from Unreal manually but that's absurd, obviously there's something wrong. This is the action in Blender:

[image]

And this is the animation imported in Unreal. Notice that the zero frame is a T-pose, which causes a flicker on each loop

[image]

Comment: Let us see the amin in Unreal to demonstrate the flickering.

Comment: Here https://gfycat.com/deadoddballeuropeanpolecat

Comment: Why can't you just delete the keyframe in unreal? That would solve your problem.

Comment: I could, yes, but what if I have a lot of characters and animations? It  would be a lot of manual work. I must be doing something wrong. Does it happen to you when you export animations?